# Date format forcing with a date field

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, datefield

I use this code in a Django project with bootstrap :

File : forms.py

```
start_date = forms.DateField(
    label='Expiration Date Range', required=False, input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'])
```

The problem is that when I select a date in the widget that appears when I click on the form's field 'Expiration Date Range', the date is formated like 30/03/2014 and NOT 2014-03-30.

I have tested a lot of tricks to force a %Y-%m-%d format but no one have worked.

Does someone see the problem ?

Thanks

Thom

Comment: In my settings.py :

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

Comment: What tricks have you tried?  Have you tried altering the `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` or `DATE_FORMAT` in settings.py?